# What is the name of the fourth son

Tags: riddle

> Someone’s mother has four sons: North, South, East and ... ?

$$ \phantom{q312312312123213 sadlasjhdsajhdsak 213123123 asdojsdljdasj 12312312 }$$

Comment: @Stiv I agree with, sorry I did not see this one (despite browsing the suggested post when asking the question).

Comment: No worries - it happens! In my experience, most one-line trick questions seem to have already been posted on this site in some guise or other. I tend to default to checking for a duplicate with these!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first impression says his name is

> "What" - However, this may be just a trick and I'm fooled easily.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a trick question, then the answer could simply be:

> Someone

Comment: @Surb To make it less ambiguous, you could substitute "children" for "sons" in the question, since now they could have daughters as well. =)